# Drop/Enable Root Privilege Opening File in Python

Tags: python, root

I am running into an issue regard dropping root privileges when opening a file in /tmp. Here is the line in question:

```
open(filepath, 'wb')
```

When the program is not run with a sudo command everything works fine and here are the permissions when I so os.stat

```
posix.stat_result(st_mode=17407, st_ino=261652, st_dev=64512L, st_nlink=206, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_size=12288, st_atime=1352314677, st_mtime=1352316340, st_ctime=1352316340)
```

I run into an issue when the program is run with a sudo command. I try to drop privileges with the following

```
os.setegid(int(os.getenv("SUDO_GID")))
os.seteuid(int(os.getenv("SUDO_UID")))
```

and reenable them with

```
os.seteuid(0)
os.setegid(0)
```

The error message is

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
```

os.stat yields

```
posix.stat_result(st_mode=17407, st_ino=261652, st_dev=64512L, st_nlink=204, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_size=4096, st_atime=1352314677, st_mtime=1352316329, st_ctime=1352316329)
```

Ideally I'd like the run a particular function as if the user never called sudo by dropping and enabling root privileges accordingly.

Comment: Can you post the full code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dropping Root Permissions In Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699907/dropping-root-permissions-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably need to change from root in a process that you spawn somehow, because, if you drop root, you can't get it back again. You could try using os.fork() for this.

```
import os


def drop_permissions():
    os.setegid(int(os.getenv("SUDO_GID")))
    os.seteuid(int(os.getenv("SUDO_UID")))


def call_without_permissions(func, *args, **kw):
    in_parent = os.fork()
    if not in_parent:
        drop_permissions()
        func(*args, **kw)
        os._exit(0)
    else:
        os.waitpid(0)
```

Comment: Do you mind linking me to some example code that demonstrates how to do that?

Comment: Working on some now. However, it won't actually run, you'll have to implement a few things yourself, like your all-ready existing user changer.

Comment: Thanks for the code. Am I dropping/enabling permissions correctly with my above code? Do I even need to reenable root in this case since we are forking?

Comment: I think that you are changing your UID and GID properly. And no, you should not need to reenable root; your main process never loses root.

Comment: I tried your code, but unfortunately it didn't solve the original problem. I am wondering if it has to do with the fact that I'm not changing privileges properly.

Comment: Try again, using the code above which sets both the real and effective GID and UID for the process.

Comment: @pydsigner "if you drop root, you can't get it back again" - not true, that's what effective UID/GID are used for. See [here](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/083) for a longer explanation.

Comment: Hmm. In that case, I don't know what your problem is.