# Pygame display init on headless Raspberry Pi Zero (Raspbian Buster Lite)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pygame, raspberry-pi-zero, debian-buster

I have Pi Zero running Raspbian Buster Lite, there's no display attached. It runs a python program at startup (crontab @reboot entry), something like this:

`@reboot sudo su username /home/username/launcher.sh >> /home/username/crontab.log 2>&1`

I have to initialize pygame display, because I need to process the Sound object end events. Without initializing the display, the events are not triggered.

The code breaks at this line, with error "pygame.error: Unable to open a console terminal"

```
    os.putenv('SDL_VIDEODRIVER', 'dummy')
    pygame.display.init()  # error at this line
```

My code used to work in the previous Raspbian (Stretch) version. I have experimented with all kinds of drivers, added/removed `pygame.display.set_mode((1, 1))`, but no luck.

I am aware of the other posts that tackle with the same question, but I have exhausted all those approaches - changing the driver to fbcon, skipping the set_mode line, etc. The only thing that works is running the program as root:

`@reboot /home/username/launcher.sh >> /home/username/crontab.log 2>&1`

But it's a bad idea, from the security perspective. I'd rather run it as unpriviliged user.

Is there a new kind of hack to get it past the `display.init()`?

Comment: It's not a solution, but if you can not work around starting as root, you could also consider dropping privileges after startup - https://stackoverflow.com/a/15707075/1730895 . At least this stops the script maintaining the execution as root.

Comment: I have the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70757953/pygame-display-init-fail-to-initialize-framebuffer-for-non-root-user), have you found a fix @Passiday ?

Answer (score 0):

[`pygame.init`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html) initializes all Pygame modules. You do not need to initialize all Pygame modules, only the ones you need. For playing music it is sufficient to initialize [`pygame.mixer`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html). Some examples

```py
import pygame

pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load('music.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play()

while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
   pygame.time.delay(10)

pygame.mixer.quit()
```

```py
import pygame

pygame.mixer.init()
my_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('music.mp3')
my_sound.play(0)

while pygame.mixer.get_busy():
    pygame.time.delay(10)

pygame.quit()
```

```py
import pygame.mixer

pygame.mixer.init()
my_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('sound.wav')
my_sound.play(0)
pygame.time.wait(int(my_sound.get_length() * 1000))

pygame.mixer.quit()
```

---

However, you cannot use the event module because it is tied to the display module.

Comment: I had to do the display init exactly because I needed the sound events. Eventually I was forced to implement my own event solution using Timer from threading because there was a limit of events in pygame.