# Upstart - how to send reload signal to script started as different user?

Tags: python, linux, centos, daemon, upstart

I have python program (couple of scripts) that need to be run as daemon on remote machine which is CentOS 6.4. So, I thought Upstart is the way to go.

Basic requirements are:

- Easy way to start/stop daemon app
- Respawn app if it crashes
- App must run under non-privileged user
- Be able to handle SIGHUP to reload config

Upstart version on that server is 0.6.5, so stanzas [setuid](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#setuid) and [setgid](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#setgid) are not available (they appear only in 1.4). So I use [official workaround](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#run-a-job-as-a-different-user) from cookbook. I am able to start/stop my app, but my main problem is that my app isn't receiving reload signal.

I'll provide stripped scripts that can reproduce the issue.

Python script (`app.py`):

```
import os
import time
import signal
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='hup.log', level=logging.INFO,
    format="%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s")
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


running = True

def run():
    log.info('PROGRAM STARTUP')
    log.info('Current pid: %d' % os.getpid())

    while running:
        log.info('Doing some hard work')
        time.sleep(10)
    else:
        log.info('PROGRAM TEARDOWN')

def signal_handler(signum, frame):
    log.info("Received Signal: %s at frame: %s" % (signum, frame))

    if signum == signal.SIGTERM:
        log.info('Received request to terminate daemon (SIGTERM)')
        global running
        running = False
    elif signum == signal.SIGHUP:
        log.info('Received reload config request (SIGHUP)')
        pass  # reload config here


signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, signal_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)

run()
```

And Upstart config (`hup.conf`):

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
respawn limit 10 5

chdir /home/dev/prj/im

script
    # activate the virtual environment
    . /home/dev/.virtualenvs/myvenv/bin/activate

    # This line runs script as root
    # exec python app.py

    # this is official workaround for running prcesses as different
    # user in upstart version prior to 1.4
    # Run as user 'dev'
    exec su -s /bin/sh -c 'exec "$0" "$@"' dev -- python app.py
end script
```

Output (as you can see, actual process with `python app.py` is having different PID than upstart shows):

```
[dev@localhost ~]$ sudo start hup
hup start/running, process 8608
[dev@localhost ~]$ ps -elf | grep app.py
F S UID        PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  STIME TTY          TIME CMD
4 S root      8608     1  0  80   0 - 16143 wait   19:53 ?        00:00:00 su -s /bin/sh -c exec "$0" "$@" dev -- python app.py
4 S dev       8613  8608  0  80   0 -  7866 poll_s 19:53 ?        00:00:00 python app.py
[dev@localhost ~]$ sudo reload hup
[dev@localhost ~]$ sudo stop hup
hup stop/waiting
```

Log shows no reload signal received:

```
2013-09-19 20:00:36,092: INFO: PROGRAM STARTUP
2013-09-19 20:00:36,093: INFO: Current pid: 8613
2013-09-19 20:00:36,093: INFO: Doing some hard work
2013-09-19 20:00:45,287: INFO: Received Signal: 15 at frame: <frame object at 0xba2dd0>
2013-09-19 20:00:45,287: INFO: Received request to terminate daemon (SIGTERM)
2013-09-19 20:00:45,287: INFO: PROGRAM TEARDOWN
```

But when I uncomment the line in `hup.conf` with `exec python app.py` (and comment one with `exec su...`), everything works, except the app is running as root.

```
[dev@localhost ~]$ sudo start hup
hup start/running, process 8811
[dev@localhost ~]$ ps -elf | grep app.py
F S UID        PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  STIME TTY          TIME CMD
4 S root      8811     1  0  80   0 -  8412 poll_s 20:13 ?        00:00:00 python app.py
[dev@localhost ~]$ sudo reload hup
[dev@localhost ~]$ sudo stop hup
hup stop/waiting
```

Log file shows SIGHUP signal has been received:

```
2013-09-19 20:13:40,290: INFO: PROGRAM STARTUP
2013-09-19 20:13:40,290: INFO: Current pid: 8811
2013-09-19 20:13:40,291: INFO: Doing some hard work
2013-09-19 20:13:59,739: INFO: Received Signal: 1 at frame: <frame object at 0x7d44c0>
2013-09-19 20:13:59,739: INFO: Received reload config request (SIGHUP)
2013-09-19 20:13:59,739: INFO: Doing some hard work
2013-09-19 20:14:04,313: INFO: Received Signal: 15 at frame: <frame object at 0x7d44c0>
2013-09-19 20:14:04,313: INFO: Received request to terminate daemon (SIGTERM)
2013-09-19 20:14:04,313: INFO: PROGRAM TEARDOWN
```

My main question is how to make `reload` command work when I run script under different user on this old version of upstart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up running my script as root and then dropping privileges to desired user.
To run script as root I've uncommented `exec python app.py` from Upstart config above.
To drop privileges I use slightly modified code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699907/dropping-root-permissions-in-python/2699996#2699996) answer:

```
def drop_privileges(uid_name, gid_name):
    '''If running as root, this function will try to change current uid and gid
    to given values.
    May raise OSError in case of error.
    :param uid_name: Name of the user we need to be running as.
    :param gid_name: Name of the group we need to be running as.
    '''

    starting_uid = os.getuid()
    starting_gid = os.getgid()

    log.info('drop_privileges: started as %s/%s' %
        (pwd.getpwuid(starting_uid).pw_name,
        grp.getgrgid(starting_gid).gr_name))

    if starting_uid == 0:
        # If we started as root, drop privs and become the specified user/group
        log.info("drop_privileges: trying to drop provileges to '%s'" % uid_name)

        # Get the uid/gid from the name
        running_uid = pwd.getpwnam(uid_name).pw_uid
        running_gid = grp.getgrnam(gid_name).gr_gid

        # Try setting the new uid/gid
        # These calls may result in exception, let it propagate back
        # Exception thrown is: OSError (e.errno == 1 means 'Operation not
        # permitted')
        os.setgid(running_gid)
        os.setuid(running_uid)

        final_uid = os.getuid()
        final_gid = os.getgid()
        log.info('drop_privileges: running as %s/%s' %
            (pwd.getpwuid(final_uid).pw_name,
             grp.getgrgid(final_gid).gr_name))
```