# ImportError: No module named boto3 on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am running my AWS EC2 instance and when I try to run my web app, MyCoolApp.py I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "MyCoolApp.py", line 9, in <module>
    import boto3
ImportError: No module named boto3
```

This is after I try to start my application which I do, and used to do before I made this latest change with the following command:

```
[ec2-user@ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX CoolApp]$ sudo python MyCoolApp.py
```

As you can guess I am trying to import Boto3 for use and I do that in the my python application with the following code at the top of my program:

```
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash
from datetime import datetime
import time, os, random, json
import urllib
import boto3
```

Lastly, because I know you are going to ask this, YES I already installed Boto3 and when I run pip freeze I can see it. This is the output below:

```
[ec2-user@ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX CoolApp]$ pip freeze
alembic==0.9.9
aws-cfn-bootstrap==1.4
awscli==1.15.83
Babel==0.9.4
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.4.0.2
blinker==1.4
boto==2.48.0
boto3==1.9.87
botocore==1.12.87
chardet==2.0.1
click==6.7
cloud-init==0.7.6
colorama==0.2.5
configobj==4.7.2
docutils==0.14
ecdsa==0.11
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-Login==0.4.1
Flask-Mail==0.9.1
Flask-Migrate==2.1.1
Flask-Mobility==0.1.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2
futures==3.2.0
hibagent==1.0.0
iniparse==0.3.1
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
jmespath==0.9.3
jsonpatch==1.2
jsonpointer==1.0
kitchen==1.1.1
lockfile==0.8
Mako==1.0.7
MarkupSafe==1.0
mysql-connector-python==8.0.11
paramiko==1.15.1
PIL==1.1.6
pip-tools==3.3.2
ply==3.4
protobuf==3.5.2.post1
pyasn1==0.1.7
pycrypto==2.6.1
pycurl==7.19.0
pygpgme==0.3
pyliblzma==0.5.3
pystache==0.5.3
python-daemon==1.5.2
python-dateutil==2.7.3
python-editor==1.0.3
pyxattr==0.5.0
PyYAML==3.10
requests==1.2.3
rsa==3.4.1
s3transfer==0.1.13
simplejson==3.6.5
six==1.11.0
SQLAlchemy==1.2.7
urlgrabber==3.10
urllib3==1.24.1
virtualenv==15.1.0
Werkzeug==0.14.1
yum-metadata-parser==1.1.4
```

Now because I suspect that someone will be suggesting this I am just going to head this off now. I have these packages all installed globally to my --user. I am NOT using a virtual environment, yes I know I should be but I didn't think that I was going to need one because everything runs on the one server. Yes I acknowledge that this might be a mistake and I use them everywhere else but thats not the point here if I could get some help with this error that would be great. It starts on my local machine and works just fine it is just when I try to run it on my server it fails.

Lastly, if this is due to a conflict with packages on my server it would be great if someone could help me figure out how to remove them, instructions would be appreciated as I am on AWS AMI Linux.

Comment: You ran the script using `sudo` but `pip freeze` without, and you noted that you ran `pip install` with `--user` flag.  Did you `pip install --user` as root (i.e. with `sudo`) or your local `ec2-user`?

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3? Ensure calling `pip` and your script happens with the same Python version.

Comment: @Dunedan I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: @metatoaster I am not totally sure here what you are asking but I think this is your answer. I ran the following code to install `pip install --user -r requirements.txt` 


I was not able to run anything with `pip` and `sudo` to work in the same line so I used the `--user` flag to do the install.

Comment: So when you ran `sudo python MyCoolApp.py`, it will not have access to the packages installed with `pip install --user`, as the packages are installed local to `ec2-user` (as per the `ec2-user@ip-...` prompt included in your logs).  The act of `sudo` runs the script as the `root` user thus it won't have access to your `ec2-user` user-local Python packages.

Comment: @metatoaster That makes a TON of sense and I would not have been able to figure this out on my own. Now here in lies what I am looking at might be my downfall. I need to run `sudo python MyCoolApp.py` and the reason is that I need to define a port that is below 1024, I plan to use 80. So now is there a way to run the `pip install` command to `root`? And yes I acknowledge that this does sound crazy and might be a terrible idea, but I want to run my website that works fine currently but will not work with this latest addition because of the Boto3 requirements.

Comment: Hi Ben, can you please update your question to include these details? While it is still a little bit broad, it is still narrow enough where a short list of concise answers may be provided. (regardless, answer is coming, will take a little bit of time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So with the details as provide in the question, we have the scenario where a Python script and the environment it will be executed at has:

1. Dependency on some packages;
2. No virtualenv is used, but the Python user install directory (as the `ec2-user` user) is used instead for simplicity for the installation of the script's dependencies;
3. The script however requires root privileges to run (due to the [usage of low ports](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16564/why-are-the-first-1024-ports-restricted-to-the-root-user-only), with the elevated permission achieved via `sudo` (as the `root` user).

Naturally, running a script as `root` while the dependencies were installed local to a user other than `root` will mean that none of the dependencies will actually be accessible by that script.  As the dependencies are installed under the [`site.USER_BASE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#site.USER_BASE) for the `ec2-user`, in order for the script to be able to import its dependency while being executed under the `root` user, the location may be defined using the [`PYTHONUSERBASE`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONUSERBASE)  environment variable.

To achieve that while using `sudo`, try:

```
$ sudo PYTHONUSERBASE=/home/ec2-user/.local python MyCoolApp.py
```

If that works, great, we can move onto a more cleaner approach if desired, as this approach can potentially result in situations where the `ec2-user` user cannot remove files from their `.local` directory, as files like `.pyc` files will be written into there as the root.

A number of approaches can be done:

1. Laziest manner: `sudo pip`, install packages globally; comes with all the problems of having globally available python packages.
2. Use `sudo pip --user` instead - only local to the root user.
3. [A number of approaches at the OS level that is available on Linux may be attempted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413807/is-there-a-way-for-non-root-processes-to-bind-to-privileged-ports-on-linux)
4. Use virtualenv, and start the Python script (with `sudo` as `root`) using the `env/bin/python` created by virtualenv.  Example (uses `/var/tmp/env` as the base for demonstration):

```
$ virtualenv /var/tmp/env
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /var/tmp/env/bin/python3.6
Also creating executable in /var/tmp/env/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
$ . /var/tmp/env/bin/activate
(env) $ pip install -r requirements.txt
...
(env) $ deactivate
$ sudo /var/tmp/env/bin/python MyCoolApp.py
```

Finally, it may be beneficial to [drop root privileges back to the original user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699907/dropping-root-permissions-in-python) (or another limited user) after the port has been opened, to improve the security situation of the runtime environment.