# REDIRECT a port in ip6tables

Tags: ipv6, iptables

How can I redirect one port to another local port by using ip6tables ?
e.g. something like this : 
ip6tables -t nat -A PREROUTING -j REDIRECT -p tcp --dport 443 --to-ports 8443

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ip6tables` does not support `REDIRECT`. (Normally people use this in a NAT environment, and NAT is generally not supported with IPv6.)

If all you need to do is bind to the low port as a normal user, why not try the workaround described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413807/is-there-a-way-for-non-root-processes-to-bind-to-privileged-ports-1024-on-li/414258#414258)? Of course, in the case of Tomcat, it sounds like this would mean giving any Java process that capability.

Comment: Apparently `ip6tables` v1.4.18 and Linux kernel v3.8 support `REDIRECT`: https://sector7g.be/posts/ipv6-nat-pre-routing-with-iptables

Comment: NAT is not used with iptables, but it's supported.

Answer (score 7):

Well this is an old question, but since I need to do the same thing… Here is what I've found:

```
TPROXY

This target is only valid in the mangle table, in the PREROUTING chain and user-defined chains which are only called from this chain. It redirects the packet to a local socket without changing the packet header in any way. It can also change the mark value which can then be used in advanced routing rules. It takes three options:
--on-port port
    This specifies a destination port to use. It is a required option, 0 means the new destination port is the same as the original. This is only valid if the rule also specifies -p tcp or -p udp. 
--on-ip address
    This specifies a destination address to use. By default the address is the IP address of the incoming interface. This is only valid if the rule also specifies -p tcp or -p udp. 
--tproxy-mark value[/mask]
    Marks packets with the given value/mask. The fwmark value set here can be used by advanced routing. (Required for transparent proxying to work: otherwise these packets will get forwarded, which is probably not what you want.)
```

This is valid for ip6tables only, of course. So I guess that this is valid:

```
ip6tables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j TPROXY --on-port 8443
```

However, I didn't try it yet.

Comment: You'll find it more difficult than REDIRECT in IPv4… The TPROXY has a special behavior in the mangle table, so you'll need to use marks on it and advanced routing.

Comment: which netfilter-Version is needed for "--on-ip" ? ip6tables v1.4.8 (Packaged with Debian Squeeze) doesn't work. Thanks in advance !

Comment: After a short search in /usr/share/doc/iptables/changelog.Debian.gz on my testing box, it seems that it has been included in 1.4.11.1-1, as mentionned in http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=529954