# start rails server in windows on port 80?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows

I'm on a Windows machine, and I'm trying to start a rails app on port 80. I'm running the command prompt as an administrator, but when I try `rails server --port=80`, I get

```
TCPServer Error: Permission denied - bind(2)
```

Running on port 81 works fine, though, and I'm not running anything else on port 80. What do I need to do?

Comment: Do you have any other web servers running? What happens when you go to `http://localhost/`?

Comment: @Garrett, nope, no other web servers running. I just get a standard "Oops! This link appears to be broken" error (in Chrome).

Comment: Oops, I lied. I ran `netstat -a` and apparently there was something running by default. Question solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran netstat -a and apparently there was something already running on port 80 by default. (I'd delete the question if I could.)

Answer (score 1):

On some Linux systems you need to be root to bind to ports less than 1024.

Comment: If you are running Linux Kernel 2.6.24 or above and have libcap installed, you can allow program to bind to ports under 1014 as non-root user. See more at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/414258