# Why is root required for listening on the loopback in Java?

Tags: java, sockets

How come when I try listening to a loopback host in Java (using a plain old socket), it requires root access, yet if I use nio, it doesn't? If I tried listening on any other language on the loopback, it doesn't require any elevated privileges too.

This is my code right now:

```
import java.net.*;

class Test
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
        throws Exception
    {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket( 80 );
        while( true )
        {
            Socket socket = server.accept();
            System.out.print( "." );
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this as a normal user, this exception is thrown: `Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Permission denied`. Yet when I run this as root, it works fine as expected.

Comment: It is not about Java, it's about OS permissions. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413807/is-there-a-way-for-non-root-processes-to-bind-to-privileged-ports-1024-on-li

Comment: Argh, didn't realize that I was listening on 8080 on the other one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need root permissions to bind a socket in the port range 0-1023. These ports are used for common services like HTTP and SSH and it would be dangerous to allow random users to bind their arbitrary applications to these ports.

See wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Well-known_ports

**Edit**: Keep in mind that arbitrary applications can *connect* to well-known ports, just not *bind* to them. Otherwise users would not be able to run honest programs ssh or mozilla. This is likely why you are not able to reproduce this error in other languages.