# What's the standard way of dealing with apps that need to access privileged ports < 1024?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I've recently found the need to elevate an app to a higher privilege level in order to `bind()` to a port < 1024.

I've been running it with `sudo`, which is fine for internal testing, but deploying it running as root is generally a very bad idea.

I've heard of setuid root, but when I looked at the source code for `lighthttpd` for example it shows:

```
#ifdef HAVE_GETUID
    if (!i_am_root && issetugid()) {
        /* we are setuid-root */

        log_error_write(srv, __FILE__, __LINE__, "s",
                "Are you nuts ? Don't apply a SUID bit to this binary");

        server_free(srv);
        return -1;
    }
#endif
```

What then is the generally accepted method to allow binding to a privileged port?  I only need higher privilege for bind. After that it can be running as a normal user.

These are the ones I've heard of, but doesn't seem to be what most software is using which is why I'm asking this question.

- setuid - root
- setcap

Comment: Interesting answers here: http://serverfault.com/questions/268099/bind-to-ports-less-than-1024-without-root-access

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413807/is-there-a-way-for-non-root-processes-to-bind-to-privileged-ports-1024-on-l

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign the `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` `capability` to the binary, or run as `root` to acquire the port and immediately drop permissions.

Comment: Yes it does appear that this might be the answer.  Start off high and drop down rather than the other way around.  Or using capabilities.  I just had a play around with setuid(0) and it doesn't work on Ubuntu by default, you still have to set CAP_SETUID capabilities.  So it would seem setuid is old school. Capabilities or starting high and dropping down is how it would seem apache and the like do it.

Comment: To grant select capabilities to a specific python2 "project" (and not all python users) see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21895123/1724577