# Using SSL with Playframework

Tags: ssl, playframework

I'm attempting to use SSL with my Playframework 1.2.5 application but can't seem to get it to work.

I have an SSL certificate from GoDaddy.
I reference the key & crt files from application.conf as follows:

```
%prod.https.port=443
%prod.certificate.key.file=conf/hawkanalytics.key
%prod.certificate.file=conf/hawkanalytics.com.crt
```

However, I'm getting the following error when attempting to access the application:

```
22:49:33,836 INFO  ~ Listening for HTTPS on port 443 ...
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at play.server.ssl.SslHttpServerContextFactory$PEMKeyManager.<init>(SslHttpServerContextFactory.java:94)
        at play.server.ssl.SslHttpServerContextFactory$PEMKeyManager.<clinit>(SslHttpServerContextFactory.java:79)
        at play.server.ssl.SslHttpServerContextFactory.<clinit>(SslHttpServerContextFactory.java:47)
        at play.server.ssl.SslHttpServerPipelineFactory.getPipeline(SslHttpServerPipelineFactory.java:29)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink$Boss.registerAcceptedChannel(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:274)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink$Boss.run(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:239)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:102)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
22:49:43,372 ERROR ~
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at play.server.ssl.SslHttpServerContextFactory$PEMKeyManager.<init>(SslHttpServerContextFactory.java:94)
        at play.server.ssl.SslHttpServerContextFactory$PEMKeyManager.<clinit>(SslHttpServerContextFactory.java:79)
        at play.server.ssl.SslHttpServerContextFactory.<clinit>(SslHttpServerContextFactory.java:47)
        at play.server.ssl.SslHttpServerPipelineFactory.getPipeline(SslHttpServerPipelineFactory.java:29)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink$Boss.registerAcceptedChannel(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:274)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink$Boss.run(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:239)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:102)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
22:49:43,504 DEBUG ~ Invalid certificate
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1031)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:508)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:759)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:727)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:938)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:656)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:317)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:207)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:75)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:792)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:352)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:334)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:207)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:75)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:94)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.processSelectedKeys(AbstractNioWorker.java:372)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:246)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:38)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:102)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Comment: What version of Play are you using? It is most relevant.

Comment: Play 1.2.5 (question edited to include this)

Answer (score 2):

check if the ".key" file you using is RSA PRIVATE KEY or just PRIVATE KEY.

Play framework seems to need RSA PRIVATE KEY with the header 
"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"

To convert: 
[How to convert a private key to an RSA private key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733536/how-do-i-convert-a-private-key-to-an-rsa-private-key).

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work following the directions in the [production mode documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.3.x/production) and a free certificate from [startssl](https://www.startssl.com)

To test this is locally add the following entry to your hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 my-ssl-domain.com
```

Next copy the certificate to `play-app/conf/host.cert`. 
Now open your key file in a text editor.
If you see a line `Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED` at the top of your your keyfile it is encrypted. I decrypted mine using the startssl webinterface, but you should be able to achieve the same from the command line using

```
openssl rsa –in my_downloaded_ssl_key.key -out play-app/conf/host.key
```

if your key is unencrypted you can copy it directly to `play-app/conf/host.key`

Finally edit `application.conf` and add the following lines:

```
https.port=443
certificate.key.file=conf/host.key
certificate.file=conf/host.cert
certificate.password=my-private-key-password
trustmanager.algorithm=JKS
```

i tested this in dev mode with `sudo play run .`. 
I'm using sudo to bind to ports 443. You can find better approaches for this particular problem [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413807/is-there-a-way-for-non-root-processes-to-bind-to-privileged-ports-1024-on-l)

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Play 1.x but according to the [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.4/production) on HTTPS configuration it states:

> You need to put your certificates in the conf directory. Play supports X509 certificates and keystore certificates. The X509 certificates must be named as follows:
>   **host.cert** for the certificate and **host.key** for the key. If you are using keystore, then, by default it should be named **certificate.jks**.

I'm not 100% certain that it is mandatory but that means you should have conf like this:

```
%prod.https.port=443
%prod.certificate.key.file=conf/host.key
%prod.certificate.file=conf/host.cert
```

Comment: I tried conf/host.key & conf/host.cert but got the same result.

Comment: I have finally managed to get Lighttpd working as a reverse proxy w/ SSL in front of PlayFramework as an alternative. As a side note - I used the exact same cert files for lighttpd.