# How to convert a private key to an RSA private key?

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, amazon-iam

Let me explain my question first. I bought a certificate from a CA and used the following format to generate the csr and the private key:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout server.key -out server.csr
```

When I open the server.key file, I see that it begins with "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----"

I use the SSL cert on my server and everything looks fine.

Now I want to upload the same cert to AWS IAM so that I can use it for by beanstalk load balancer. I use the following command from this aws doc http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/InstallCert.html#SubmitCSRCertAuth

```
iam-servercertupload -b public_key_certificate_file  -k privatekey.pem -s certificate_object_name
```

I change the cert file names as required but keep getting this error: "400 MalformedCertificate Invalid Private Key."

The interesting thing is, on the aws doc page, the sample private key that they show starts with "-------Begin RSA Private Key--------"

Is there a way to convert my private key to an RSA private key using openssl?

Answer (score 199, accepted):

Newer versions of OpenSSL say `BEGIN PRIVATE KEY` because they contain the private key + an OID that identifies the key type (this is known as PKCS8 format). To get the old style key (known as either PKCS1 or traditional OpenSSL format) you can do this:

```
openssl rsa -in server.key -out server_new.key
```

If you are using OpenSSL 3, you need to add `-traditional` :

```
openssl rsa -in server.key -out server_new.key -traditional
```

Alternately, if you have a PKCS1 key and want PKCS8:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in privkey.pem
```

Comment: This is also the solution to getting weird error messages like `Invalid PEM structure, '-----BEGIN...' missing.` from tools like Cyberduck while pure SSH with the same key is working.

Comment: This worked for me.

Windows users can get OpenSSL here: http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

Comment: Thank you! I was getting `A client error (MalformedCertificate) occurred when calling the UploadServerCertificate operation: Unable to parse certificate. Please ensure the certificate is in PEM format.` and running this on my private key fixed it!

Comment: For reference: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/20065304/53974 for a more complete explanation.

Comment: how do we do the opposite of this?  I need a `Private Key` from an `RSA Private Key`?

Comment: `openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in privkey.pem` will write a PKCS8 to STDOUT

Comment: what should the old style say `BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY`?

Comment: **update:** in OpenSSL 3.0.0 (released 2021) up `openssl rsa` now defaults to PKCS8; to get PKCS1 use `openssl rsa -traditional` _or_ `openssl pkey -traditional` (the lattter has been an alternative since 1.0.0 in 2010)

Answer (score 36):

This may be of some help (do not literally write out the backslashes '\' in the commands, they are meant to indicate that "everything has to be on one line"):

[image: Which Command to Apply When]

It seems that all the commands (in grey) take any type of key file (in green) as "in" argument. Which is nice.

Here are the commands again for easier copy-pasting:

```
openssl rsa                                                -in $FF -out $TF
openssl rsa -aes256                                        -in $FF -out $TF
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt                              -in $FF -out $TF
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -v2 aes-256-cbc -v2prf hmacWithSHA256 -in $FF -out $TF
```

and

```
openssl rsa -check -in $FF
openssl rsa -text  -in $FF
```

Comment: The "graphml" file of the image (which can be edited with [yworks yed](https://www.yworks.com/products/yed) for example) can be found [here](https://github.com/dtonhofer/diagrams/tree/master/OpenSSL_Commands)

Answer (score 29):

To Convert `BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY` to `BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY`:

```
ssh-keygen -p -m PEM -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: This behaviour is documented indirectly on the ssh-keygen manpage, but the usage of the -m flag is actually not mentioned for other operation modes than -i and -o

Comment: Beware that this would overwrite the key file. So make a backup first.

Comment: Is there a way to specify a new output file with this command?