# Certificate generated by Openssl Contains "PRIVATE KEY" instead of "RSA PRIVATE KEY"

Tags: encryption, openssl, rsa

Initially we were using OpenSSL 0.9.8e to import the certificate. This version of OpenSSL used to create the Private key Bio using the header "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----". now we have upgraded the OpenSSL to 1.0.1. in this version of OpenSSL when we import a certificate, the Private Key Bio is creates using the header "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----".

This difference is causing the issue in exporting the certificate to Other devices.

Can somebody please help me to debug this issue?

Thanks in advance,
Azeem

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i convert a private key to an RSA private key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733536/how-do-i-convert-a-private-key-to-an-rsa-private-key)

Comment: Above mentioned thread contains the solution but it is the OpenSSL command to get the old style key. I was hoping for the code in OpenSSL which is causing this particular issue.

Comment: Exporting certs sounds ok, but why would you want to distribute a private key for heaven's sake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See `PEM_write_bio_PrivateKey` and `PEM_write_bio_RSAPrivateKey`. I'm not sure when it occurred, but its likely due to this change (from https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/pem.html):

> The old PrivateKey write routines are retained for compatibility. New
>   applications should write private keys using the
>   PEM_write_bio_PKCS8PrivateKey() or PEM_write_PKCS8PrivateKey()
>   routines because they are more secure (they use an iteration count of
>   2048 whereas the traditional routines use a count of 1) unless
>   compatibility with older versions of OpenSSL is important.
>
> The PrivateKey read routines can be used in all applications because
>   they handle all formats transparently.

Comment: So does that mean I wont be able to get the older format of certificate with newer OpenSSL code.
is it possible somehow to disable the OpenSSL code which is causing the change of Key format and generate the key format as it was done in older OpenSSL?