# Get RSA PRIVATE KEY instead of PRIVATE KEY

Tags: openssl

I have command that generates `PRIVATE KEY` in client.key file. But I need `RSA PRIVATE KEY`. How to achieve that?

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout client.key -out client.csr -config openssl.cnf -reqexts v3_client_req -nodes -subj "/C=US/ST=California/L=Hawthorne/O=PhilNet/CN=Client/"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DUPE** but noticed after I had answered: [How to convert a private key to an RSA private key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733536/how-to-convert-a-private-key-to-an-rsa-private-key?rq=1)

1. do `openssl rsa -in client.key -out client.old.key`. If you want the old-format file encrypted see the man page or help message for a list of options (like `-aes128` or `-des3`), although since you requested unencrypted on the command giving the new-format (PKCS8) file I'm guessing that's what you want for the old-format file. Plus the old-format encryption uses a much weaker PBKDF than new-format (PKCS8) does; there are numerous existing Qs on multiple stacks about that.
2. alternatively, instead of generating the key *in* the `req -new` command, generate it separately:

   ```
   openssl genrsa -out client.key 2048 # old command uses old-format keyfile
   # can add option to encrypt old-format file, similar to above
   openssl req -new -key client.key -out client.csr -config ....
   ```
3. (not recommended) use an *old* OpenSSL version: 0.9.x, current before 2010 and still supported until 2015, defaulted the output from `req -new[key]` to old-format (even though OpenSSL *supported* PCKS8 since about 2000).