# tcp program can't listen on port 80

Tags: networking, tcp, network-programming

I wrote a simple tcp server program and make it listen on port 80
then I notice from

```
netstat -tulpn|grep "tcp"
```

that the tcp server listening port is changed to a random port, but not 80

I tried other ports like `2000`, the tcp server program runs fine and can listen on that port
but `80` is not possible

I checked whether there are other processes that are listening on port 80, 
originally there is a `httpd`, but I killed it
and still my tcp server can't listen on port 80

I tried several machines, the phenomenon is the same
are there any causes for this? and how to make my program listen on port 80?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be root to listen to ports below 1024.

Comment: thanks .I got the occupied program by running `sudo lsof -i:80` or `sudo netstat -anp|grep 80` .

Answer (score 3):

Ports below 1024 are restricted. If you are just playing around it's easy enough to run your program as root but if you want to write an application that you don't want to run as root for security reasons but still be able to bind to a restricted port you may want to look into the [Linux capabilities system](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html).

Here's a link to an answer on how to use the [`setcap` utility on Linux.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/414258/2167797).