# Python heroku error H20 App boot timeout, R10 boot timeout

Tags: python, heroku, timeout

I do as the examples: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/, and I can run it well on my own machine after "foreman start", however when I deploy it on heroku, I got R10 timeout error.

I wrote the Procfileas :

```
web: python flaskr.py
```

and in order to run the "git push heroku master" command, I delete the "disreibute==0.6.24" sentence because if not, I would get an error as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'install' is not defined
```

So I don't know whether it is the Procfile or the requirements.txt file is wrong or something else is wrong. I almost read all articles I have found but the problem is not solved yet.

Besides, the example used SQLite3 database, I don't know whether it has something to do with this..

In the last, I will list the logs here:

```
at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path=/ host=tranquil-tor-4127.herokuapp.com request_id=8a088587-bee9-40e9-a686-0555843c191b fwd="8.35.201.53" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
Stopping process with SIGKILL
Process exited with status 137
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=tranquil-tor-4127.herokuapp.com request_id=59ccb901-e988-430d-93e8-f83a8930e60b fwd="8.35.201.50" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=tranquil-tor-4127.herokuapp.com request_id=7b76850f-7c25-481f-8216-542d9baaa769 fwd="8.35.201.51" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
Slug compilation started
State changed from crashed to starting
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=tranquil-tor-4127.herokuapp.com request_id=5601bbce-b00c-4927-8d9c-ac534745859d fwd="8.35.201.52" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I noticed that slug compilation can finish normally and then R10 error follows.

Comment: The said article does not say anything about Heroku.. Their are some differences when you deploy your application locally and when on Heroku. Heroku requires virtual environment for app deployment. Please refer https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python for deploying your app on Heroku

Comment: heroku does not support sqlite3.

Answer (score 3):

The following solution for our node.js app might help anyone who ends up here.

Listening to 127.0.0.1 leads to the **code=H20 desc="App boot timeout"** problem for us. Changing the **listening address to 0.0.0.0** solves the problem.

Also, don't use your own port, but instead **use the environment variable PORT** , which is passed to your app environment variables by heroku. Otherwise, you'll also get this problem.

Here is our node code:

```
const { PORT=3000, LOCAL_ADDRESS='0.0.0.0' } = process.env
server.listen(PORT, LOCAL_ADDRESS, () => {
  const address = server.address();
  console.log('server listening at', address);
});
```

So, try to log your listening address and port and check them firstly.

Comment: It took me 2 hours to come to this! Thank you!

Comment: Bravo mate! Struggled for hours to get to this! Kudos to you!!!!

Comment: Sorry if its a dumb question, but I think the code you provided is in another programming language. How do I change these ports and local adresses in a python flask api? Or is it in the procfile?

Comment: @Caldass_ See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20212894/how-do-i-get-flask-to-run-on-port-80