# Flask app can't find javascript file through relative path?

Tags: flask

In my Flask app. If the page's path is `http://example.com/product/6`. I can't import js file in this page's html file like this :

`<script src="js/main.js"></script>`

The browser will search the js file in `http://example.com.product/js/main.js`, and return 404 error.

So, what should I do to fix this ?

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`url_for`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.url_for) to generate the URLs for your static assets.

```
<script src="{% url_for('static', filename='js/main.js' %}"></script>
```

Comment: You asked about getting the JavaScript files to load. You should use `url_for` for that. If you want to know how to reference URLs inside JavaScript files, that is a completely different question that can be answered either by placing the URLs in JavaScript inside a template file or by placing the URLs directly into the JavaScript files.

Answer (score 2):

You should make your static resources use the root directory (if that's where you're keeping them all).

So if your directory looks like this:

```
.
├── app.py
└── static
    ├── css
    ├── img
    └── js
        └── main.js
```

try adding a `/` onto your javascript URL so it isn't just appended onto the page URL.

e.g. `<script src="js/main.js"></script>` will then go to `http://example.com/js/main.js`.

FYI - You should be using a web server such as [apache](http://httpd.apache.org/) or [nginx](http://nginx.org/) to server your static files as they are a lot better at it than Flask.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why Apache or Nginx are a lot better than Flask? In what way?

Comment: @zwep I actually wrote a bit more information [in a different answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20213086/1401034) but basically for performance (Flask only serves one request at a time) and security are the top priorities. They are specifically designed to handle more traffic and be configurable for things like SSL termination.