# How to get all available Command Options to set environment variables?

Tags: python, flask

The [flask manual about Setting Command Options](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/cli/#setting-command-options) only talks about the command `FLASK_RUN_PORT` to set environment variables that can be loaded by *Click*.

How can i find the other options and use them with the pattern `FLASK_COMMAND_OPTION` ?

I want to set it to my vscode launch.json.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can access all available commands by executing in a shell :

```
flask --help
```

> ```
> [...]
> Commands:
>       db     Perform database migrations.
>       run    Runs a development server.
>       shell  Runs a shell in the app context.
> ```

Then if you want to list all available options for a given command like `run`:

```
flask run --help
```

> ```
> Options:
>       -h, --host TEXT                 The interface to bind to.
>       -p, --port INTEGER              The port to bind to.
>       --reload / --no-reload          Enable or disable the reloader.  By default
>                                       the reloader is active if debug is enabled.
>       --debugger / --no-debugger      Enable or disable the debugger.  By default
>                                       the debugger is active if debug is enabled.
>       --eager-loading / --lazy-loader
>                                       Enable or disable eager loading.  By default
>                                       eager loading is enabled if the reloader is
>                                       disabled.
>       --with-threads / --without-threads
>                                       Enable or disable multithreading.
>       --help                          Show this message and exit.
> ```

So you can use them with the pattern like in the doc examples, you just have to concatenate the name and the options with underscores, in ALLCAPS:

```
export FLASK_RUN_PORT=8000
export FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0
```

You can also define boolean options :

```
export FLASK_RUN_RELOAD=True   
export FLASK_RUN_RELOAD=False
```

NOTE : `flask --help` will list default commands, but if you define your app before executing this help (`export FLASK_APP=my_app.py`), you will also get all custom commands.

> ```
> Commands:
>       db      Perform database migrations.
>       deploy
>       run     Runs a development server.
>       shell   Runs a shell in the app context.
>       test    perform tests
> ```

Comment: Hi, is 'FLASK_RUN_HOST' a default commands? I just want to find other default commands.

Comment: all commands appear at the end of the help documentation, you just have to concatenate the name and the options with underscores, in ALLCAPS.

Comment: For flask run, your method works well. However, if I set the app.config['FLASK_RUN_PORT']=8000 in code and do flask run, then it still starts up on port 5000

Comment: @variable it's hard to debug this without context, could you create a question and define what you've tried exactly?

Comment: I mean setting port via config variable does not work

Comment: @variable See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20212894/how-do-i-get-flask-to-run-on-port-80