# How to change Flask server host/port using config file?

Tags: python, flask

For a basic 'hello world' webpage using flask, I'm trying to change the default host:port on the flask server from 127.0.0.1:5000 to something else using a config file. I have created a config file with just the following setting:

```
SERVER_NAME = '127.0.0.23:5001'
```

and accessed it in the python file using app.config.from_pyfile(filepath...):

I am starting the flask server using 'flask run', but when I try to access the webpage using a browser on the new host/port, it says unable to connect. I can't access the webpage on the default host/port (127.0.0.1:5000) either.

I've also tried running the flask server using app.run() (and running as a regular python script) instead of 'flask run' and the host/port change works correctly using the same config file, but how can I get it to work using 'flask run'?

My flask version is 1.0.2 and python is 3.7.1 running on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/config/#SERVER_NAME

> Inform the application what host and port it is bound to.

This parameter only *inform[s] the application what host and port it is bound to.*

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45860843/4653485), you can try

```
flask run --host=127.0.0.23 --port=5001
```

Note that in production, you should definitely not use the debug server. And in development, the default config is fine for most cases.