# trying to run AolServer on port 80/443 on linux Centos 6

Tags: linux, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, aolserver

In open source project,project open, I'm trying to run the server on port 80 for http and 443 for https which gave an error 
`[-nssock:driver-] Error: nssock: failed to listen on 0.0.0.0:80: Permission denied`

and also is there anything else required to enable https port(like certification,etc)

Comment: are there any other applications which already used the port 80?

Comment: @BMW: no other application is running on that port.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any other applications which already used the port 80? run below command to find out what applicaiton use the resource

```
netstat -an |grep "\.80 "

lsof -i:80
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are trying to run AolServer as non-root user, but AolServer is configured to use "privileged" ports 80 and 443 (ports below 1024 are "privileged").

You may either configure your system to [allow non-root process to bind to "privileged" ports](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10735/linux-allowing-an-user-to-listen-to-a-port-below-1024), or just run AolServer as root. For the first approach also check discussion of [the capabilities system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413807/is-there-a-way-for-non-root-processes-to-bind-to-privileged-ports-1024-on-l).