# Grunt.js on port 80 (localhost)

Tags: localhost, gruntjs, virtualbox, yeoman, linux-mint

I recently became acquainted with Grunt.js and I am using `grunt serve` in VirtualBox Linux Mint terminal to setup a server but I want to be able to access it easily from anywhere using just a hostname such as `http://virtualbox`, and not `http://virtualbox:9000`. I have already switched the network adapter to bridge in VirtualBox's settings.

I altered Gruntfile.js so that it uses port 80, and used sudo on grunt serve but I have a feeling that I shouldn't be doing this.

Is there any solution to this, or am I taking entirely the wrong route? I previously used XAMPP in Windows.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413807/is-there-a-way-for-non-root-processes-to-bind-to-privileged-ports-1024-on-l