# How to config logstash to listen by snmptrap?

Tags: logstash

I am a new user of lostash and elastichsearch. I want to collection logs of network devices by snmptrap. I have a problem with logstash. Please help me!!!

+logstash.log

> {:timestamp=>"2014-12-12T16:17:28.744000+0700", :message=>"SNMP Trap listener died", :exception=>#, :backtrace=>["org/jruby/ext/socket/RubyUDPSocket.java:160:in `bind'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/snmp-1.1.1/lib/snmp/manager.rb:527:in`initialize'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/snmp-1.1.1/lib/snmp/manager.rb:572:in `create_transport'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/snmp-1.1.1/lib/snmp/manager.rb:605:in`initialize'", "/opt/logstash/lib/logstash/inputs/snmptrap.rb:69:in `snmptrap_listener'", "/opt/logstash/lib/logstash/inputs/snmptrap.rb:54:in`run'", "/opt/logstash/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:163:in `inputworker'", "/opt/logstash/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:157:in`start_input'"], :level=>:warn}

- logstash.conf

> input {
>       snmptrap {
>       type => "snmptrap"
>       port => 162
>       host => "0.0.0.0"
>       community => "test"
>       }
>       }
>      output {
>       elasticsearch {
>       host => "10.100.28.29"
>       }
>       }

p/s: sorry by bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Unix systems, non-root processes normally can't bind to ports below 1024. You have a couple of options:

- Pick another port and adjust the sending parties' configuration accordingly.
- Run Logstash as root.
- Use one of the options described in [Is there a way for non-root processes to bind to "privileged" ports on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413807/is-there-a-way-for-non-root-processes-to-bind-to-privileged-ports-1024-on-l).

Additional reading: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16564/why-are-the-first-1024-ports-restricted-to-the-root-user-only

Comment: Great! I haved sloved my issues.Thanks you very much, Magnus Bäck.