# java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: java, tomcat7, ubuntu-12.04, snmp

I want to use low port in my application (SNMP Trap Receiver on Spring web + Tomcat7). As I told in this thread [Binding Low Port to Java Program on Ubuntu Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30568335/binding-low-port-to-java-program-on-ubuntu-server?noredirect=1#comment49213056_30568335), before, I got error Permission denied. Then I change tomcat7 user group be root. But after that, I got java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address error. For every port that I try (low or high port), I always got this error.

I check if the port has used, I see that the port still free.
I check my /etc/host content, it is like this:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost 
127.0.1.1 test-server 
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts 
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback 
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes 
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters 
124.81.xx.x test-server.com
```

note: my OS is ubuntu server

Comment: What {address:port} are you binding to? and is `address` a local IP address of the localhost?

Comment: Yes, ip address of localhost (124.81.xx.xx:162)

Comment: But is it a *local* IP address of the host, or its public address via a router/firewall and port forwarding? You can't bind to the latter, only the former.

Comment: oh, the ip address is a public ip. My server only has this one ip, whereas when I try to bind/listen on localhost ip (127.0.0.1:162), the trap cannot catched. How can I solve this.
Fyi, I am not the admin of networking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should bind to `0.0.0.0` instead of trying to specify a local-address.

Comment: The listener on at 0.0.0.0:162, but when I try send trap to real ip (public ip->124.81.xx.xx), the trap is not catched

Comment: Sorry, today I try it again and it working well. I do not know why yesterday it was not working, maybe I missed something. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: You can't bind to any address that isn't a local IP address of the localhost. You can't for example bind to the outside address provided by an external router.