# Elasticsearch Bindexception cannot assign requested address

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to start my elasticsearch node and I am getting the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" BindTransportException[Failed to bind to [9300-9400]]; nested: ChannelException[Failed to bind to: /192.168.0.1:9400]; nested: BindException[Cannot assign requested address];
Likely root cause: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
```

I am not incredibly linux savvy but I googled how to check if a process is using a certain port and found the following

`lsof -n -iTCP:9400`

which returns nothing. i also tried

`netstat -tulpn | grep 9400`

which also returned nothing

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: No I was not. I was an intern at the time and my internship ended.

Comment: I was able to fix it. Binding IP address that I was using in my configurations was wrong. Fixed it and this resolved.

Answer (score 5):

Look at this: 
[Elastic Search - Ubuntu - Connection Refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35960205/elastic-search-ubuntu-connection-refused)

Your elasticsearch config for host ip is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Check your IP address and change accordingly in elasticsearch.yml and restart it.

Answer (score 0):

I too got this error in `elasticsearch.ym`l please check if

```
network.host: localhost
```

has been configured in the right way also please check the port as well.
In my case it was an IP I changed to localhost then restarted Elastic service then it worked.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30118962)