# Allow specific linux user to bind to port 443

Tags: linux, ssl, jboss

I am in charge of setting up a JBoss web application that runs over SSL, thus should be accessible over port 443.

Of course, it can be started up by user with root privileges, but that is something I'd like to avoid. I'd like to run it by non-privileged user so I can strictly control everything this application does and give no more access than needed.

However, the problem is that non-privileged users can not bind to <1024 ports. I am aware of the reasons why this is so by design, however, this security principle does not let me to practice good security with my JBoss application.

What is the best way to solve this? I'd certainly like to avoid an ugly solution like binding to port 8443 instead.

Comment: Should be on [unix.se] or [sf] IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I posted now in the Unix & Linux forum.

Comment: I think it's not strictly admin question, since common approach to solve this requires some coding and changes in application design :)

Comment: @gavv Usually it's just a single command - `setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /path/to/program`, rather than any coding. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413807/is-there-a-way-for-non-root-processes-to-bind-to-privileged-ports-on-linux

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way for non-root processes to bind to "privileged" ports on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413807/is-there-a-way-for-non-root-processes-to-bind-to-privileged-ports-on-linux)

Comment: @mikemaccana thanks for the link, I went the authbind way. Quite a long time ago, indeed.

Comment: @Passiday It's not so much for you, but to identify whether it's the same question (or the same answer) for other people, to avoid duplicates on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @mikemaccana yes, it's the same question.

Answer (score 0):

**1.**

Common approach to write network services that use privileged ports is:

- start service as root;
- create socket and bind it to privileged port;
- drop root privileges by switching to unprivileged user:

  - use [`setuid(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setuid.2.html) to drop privileges irreversibly;
  - use [`seteuid(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/seteuid.2.html) to drop privileges but remain able to switch back to root.

**2.**

Common approach to allow unprivileged users to start privileged service is to set `setuid bit`.

After binding to privileged port, service can switch back to `real user id` (user that started your service) or some special user (like `cron` user for cron daemon).

**3.**

Another (linux-specific) option is to give your service `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` capability without giving full root privileges.

This can be done directly in code using `libpcap` (but you still need `setuid bit`), or by attaching capability bit to executable, if your filesystem supports it (thus you don't need `setuid bit`).

Comment: I went the authbind way, it felt simpler and more natural.

Comment: I agree that it is simpler, but in my opinion it is a workaround for poorly designed programs. So I would not recommend it for "real" applications. See "BUGS" section in authbind manual page.