# BlueZ hci_le_set_scan_parameters() function fails in VC++ code

Tags: raspberry-pi3, raspbian, bluez, hci

I am running some well-known C++ sample code on Raspberry Pi 3 (running as a client on the latest Raspbian version) for communication with BLE devices (running as servers) from VS2017 C++ for Linux project in debug mode. My project compiles without errors and even warnings. I use the BlueZ library's HCI finctions. Please advise me why the call to the BlueZ hci_le_set_scan_parameters() function fails (returns -1). From

Here is the link to the original C++ code I use without any changes:https://github.com/carsonmcdonald/bluez-experiments/blob/master/experiments/scantest.c

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Obviously hci_le_set_scan_parameters() function requires root or elevated privileges. From command line sudo gatttool commands worked fine. The possible solutions like this one (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34723861/calling-a-c-function-with-root-privileges-without-executing-the-whole-program?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) to temporarily set up root privileges in the C++ code before calling the HCI function did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Besides requiring elevated privileges, there's also the possibility that your bluetooth controller is in an odd state. There are two ways to fix it:

- Just wait
- Use bluetoothctl

Run bluetoothctl as root (sudo bluetoothctl), then execute the following commands

- agent on
- default-agent
- scan on
- scan off
- agent off
- exit

That should be enough to kick your controller and get the HCI functions working again. But remember, you most likely have to have elevated privileges to execute those commands.