# FIWARE COSMOS with HDP 2.2 or 2.5 Installation

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, fiware-cosmos, hortonworks-sandbox

Based on what I have read, the mandatory tools for FIWARE COSMOS using HDP 2.5 are:

- COSMOS (HAAS engine for shared Hadoop e.g. tested with HDP 2.2)
- HDPF-based storage cluster (tested with HDP 2.2)
- [Cosmos GUI installation and configuration](https://fiware-cosmos.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.0/installation_and_administration_manual/gui/index.html) & [GitHub](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cosmos/tree/master/cosmos-gui)

Questions:

- Could the FIWARE team please share the instruction on how to install and configure Cosmos GUI to HDP 2.2 or 2.5 (installed using HortonWorks Sandbox)
- Please provide the Light-version Cosmos Big Data architecture using HDP 2.2.
- I am not sure if the HDP (2.2 or 2.5) comes with HttpFS server?

[image]

Reference: [BigData Analysis - Installation and Administration Guide](http://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/BigData_Analysis_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide)

Comment: The [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32912733/start-cosmos-gui) here is relevant to the task above. I think there is sufficient information to address the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I am gathering information here for HDP 2.5 user who would like to use the FIWARE framework and Cosmos GUI. *In the process of questioning, I found other links that help to address the issue I have in setting up HDP 2.5 for FIWARE*

Answer: HDP does not come with HttpFS, [instruction][3] to [install][4] are provided.

Suggestion: perhaps provide a Docker file to COSMOS GUI to simplify the installation to HDP? The user is expected to install HttpFS to HDP.