# How to change file capabilities on Android?

Tags: android, android-kernel

Linux has the command [setcap](http://linux.die.net/man/8/setcap) to change file capabilities. This does not seem to be supported by Android by default. Could anyone confirm this?  If so, is there a way to add this command to Android which is a branch of Linux?

As for the reason to run this command, I want to use the answer of of this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413807/is-there-a-way-for-non-root-processes-to-bind-to-privileged-ports-1024-on-l) to address the issue of using privileged ports.

Comment: android uses the linux kernel. but just because it uses the linux kernel doesn't mean all linux commands will be available. kernel != operating system.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks for the explanation.  Is there a way to add this command? I assume Android supports the capabilities, but just does not support the command to change them.

Comment: This awfully much sounds like an XY-Problem. Please explain what you are trying to do first!

Comment: @XaverKapeller I want to run this command "setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /path/to/program".  I did not want to distract people by getting into the details of what I wanted to do.  In light of your commend, I will add this information to the question.

Comment: @Hong Yes, but why are you trying to do that? Are you compiling your own Android distribution? Please explain what you are trying to achieve in the end, don't list the steps that that you think will get you there.

Comment: You might want to try rooting the device and installing BusyBox then get `setcap` somehow, but I don't think that is in the scope of StackOverflow

Comment: @XaverKapeller I edited the question. Please let me know if it is good enough.  I did a lot (many hours) research on the issue that I want to address.  I did not want to distract people to all the processes.  Instead, I want to make the question as specific as possible.

Comment: @cricket_007  Actually I checked BusyBox before posting the question.  I have not tried the app, but the list does not include setcap

Comment: @XaverKapeller sorry but I forgot to answer your question regarding compiling Android.  I have some influence on the specific Android build, but I am trying to find way to work with the existing version.

Comment: @Hong I understand what you are trying to do with `setcap`, but why? Why do you need to use a privledged port? They are called privledged for a reason. You should **not** use them. So why are trying to do this? I am continuing to ask this because there might be a much simpler and better solution to the problem you are trying to solve with `setcap`.

Comment: @XaverKapeller Though I do not mind getting all the details, I still want to make it as brief as possible. There are a few reasons.  Let me just give one: I want to run my own HTTP service, and I HAVE TO  use the default port:80 (Please do not ask why I have to use the default port.  This is beyond what I can control).

Comment: So your question is actually "How do I run a WebServer on an Android device?"

Comment: @cricket_007 No.  As I said, there are a few reasons. That is one of them. Most importantly, the service has to be done in our code, not using any third party tool.  It is only a small part of an app with many other features.

Comment: @cricket_007  That is exactly the reason that I wanted to avoid getting into the reasons that may distract people, and instead asked a very specific question.

Comment: Maybe if you briefly provided the **entire** details of what you want to do, we can maybe actually give you an answer instead of guessing what you want.

Comment: There is also a thread for [File Capabilities in Android](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-kernel/iYakEvY24n4)

Comment: @cricket_007 OK.  Let's solve the HTTP service that HAS TO use port 80 first. If this problem is solved, others may be solved accordingly. What details would you like to know.  My approach is really standard, nothing sepcial - creating a socket listening to port 80. Code new ServerSocket(80) throws  "java.net.BindException: bind failed: EACCES (Permission denied)"

Comment: @cricket_007 I red that thread before posting the question.  The Android that I have to use is V4.2.

Comment: Then you need to root the device and give your app root access.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106757/discussion-between-hong-and-cricket-007).