# Apache cannot bind :443 address for SSL even though port 443 is unused

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, ports

I recently installed Apache 2.4.20 with SSL enabled using openssl 1.0.2j.

After updating the httpd.conf and httpd-ssl.conf files and trying to start Apache while listening to port 443, I get the following error:

```
(13)Permission denied: -----: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443
(13)Permission denied: -----: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:443
no listening sockets available, shutting down
```

Here is what I have for config:

httpd.conf:

```
Listen 51000
#Listen 443
#Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

httpd-ssl.conf

```
Listen 443
```

If I comment out this line in the httpd-ssl.conf file, my apache starts up fine:

```
attempting to start apache
done
```

However with it I get the socket error every time.

I ran the following as root:

```
netstat -tlpn | grep :443
```

Returned nothing.

```
lsof -i tcp:443
```

Returned nothing.

I've read somewhere that only root can bind to addresses below 1024, but I don't know the validity of that statement. Apache is not being run here as root - would that be the issue?

Comment: I have the same problem. It seems kind of silly to even have a Listen option in ssl.conf if you cannot actually specify an HTTPS port and IP address to listen to. What's strange is that in my case, if I comment out the Listen option, then Apache defaults to listening to *:443 anyway, just not a specific IP address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that 443 is a privileged port, and you are trying to listen as a non-root user.

See: [privileged ports](https://www.w3.org/Daemon/User/Installation/PrivilegedPorts.html) and [why are privileged ports restricted to root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16564/why-are-the-first-1024-ports-restricted-to-the-root-user-only).

[There are also ways to get non-root users to bind to privileged ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413807/is-there-a-way-for-non-root-processes-to-bind-to-privileged-ports-1024-on-l).

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I was afraid it was this when I read that piece a little earlier today. I will look into the work-arounds and see if any apply for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using docker with docker-compose,

It happens when we use a non-root container like *bitnami* official images.

We used **user:root** and **network_mode: host** when it needs to get bind with **host network**.

```
  apache:
    image: bitnami/apache:2.4
    container_name: "apache"
    ports:
      - 80:80
    network_mode: host
    privileged: true
    user: root
    environment:
      DOCKER_HOST: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ./setup/apache/httpd.conf:/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/httpd.conf
```

Hope it helps!