# Tomcat6 port change to 80 not working in plesk server

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

We are trying to change the port of tomcat server from 8080 to 80 and apache port from 80 to 8081. The Apache port change is working fine but not the tomcat port change. We have changed the port in server.xml file as 80 but it is not chowing up. If we add any other port this works really fine. Can any one please let us know regarding this?

Thanks

Comment: Show the `server.xml` and the startup logfile

Comment: if Tomcat works with ports other than 80, then it could be used by other process (port 80 i mean)

Comment: May be something else is running on port `80`....

Comment: See also: [Why are the first 1024 ports restricted to the root user only?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16564)

Comment: It was earlier assigned to Apache and before changing the port for tomcat to 80 we have assigned apache port 8081 and that worked fine. Now the apache website as loading fine with the port 8081 but not tomcat.

Comment: See also: [Is there a way for non-root processes to bind to “privileged” ports on Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/413807/5221149)

Comment: The server.xml part is as below.

<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />