# Can install4j be used to allow applications to bind to privileged ports?

Tags: install4j, linux-capabilities

Many operating systems require special treatment when an application wants to bind (listen for incoming data) on a "privileged" port (a port number under 1024).

There are [various methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413807/is-there-a-way-for-non-root-processes-to-bind-to-privileged-ports-on-linux) to deal with this.

Does install4j provide functionality that allows the installed (server) application to bind to privileged ports on platforms where this is applicable?

Answer (score 0):

install4j has no special functionality for that purpose, you would have to run the launcher as root.

Comment: Running the launcher as root causes the application to be installed and ran as root? Although that might be a workaround for some, I severely dislike running my (server)applications with root privileges. Could adding Linux Capabilities (or equivalent) be added to the roadmap, if feasible?

Comment: install4j launchers do not use native code on Linux/Unix, the launcher is a shell script. So if you need a native dependency for this feature, you would have to provide it separately.