# GCP => listen tcp :443: bind: permission denied

Tags: go, https, google-cloud-platform, lets-encrypt

I have an issue trying to setup an https on Google Cloud Platform using golang + let's encrypt

- I already have a domain targeting the IP of the instance
- Also I got a let's encrypt certificate and chain saved on /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/
- I already setup myapp to use the cert and configured to run as a service using myapp.service via systemctl

And after all this configurations I always get the next error message:

---

```
Feb 14 11:29:47 https https[1982]: 2019/02/14 11:29:47 listen tcp :443: bind: permission denied
Feb 14 11:29:47 https systemd[1]: https.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 14 11:29:47 https systemd[1]: https.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 14 11:29:47 https systemd[1]: https.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: Something other process is already listening at 443.

Comment: @freakish this is not true, if another process is listening on the same port. You will get `bind: address already in use` error.

Comment: Ahh, fair enough. You are right, by default Linux servers don't allow access to low ports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I just look for more info about CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE and I found an answer of Scott Stensland inside this other post:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/455221/setcap-not-found-in-debian-9/455234#455234

Now looks fixed ... thanks

But now I have a "open /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/cert.pem: permission denied" error :\ (looking for other solutions in progress...)

Comment: Did u get final solution ?

Answer (score 15):

If you want to bind to a [privileged port](https://www.w3.org/Daemon/User/Installation/PrivilegedPorts.html) (ports less than 1024). You either need to be `root` or have the `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` capability.

Answer (score 0):

Do a port redirect using iptables. Checkout this answer by flappysocks on
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1762807/1100242