# error while attempting to bind on address ('0.0.0.0' 443) permission denied aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, unix, webhooks, py-telegram-bot-api

I'm trying to start a telegram bot on a aws unix server.
Following the example in the api of pyTelegramBotApi https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/webhook_examples/webhook_aiohttp_echo_bot.py I am setting up webhook with aiohttp, I have no problems generating the ssl certificate and the private key but I have problems in receiving connections.
On aws in the security groups section I opened the ports http 80 and https 443, both with anyware 0.0.0.0/0 but when I start the program it always returns the error in the image, both with port 80 and 443, how to solve?

[image]

Comment: Are you running it as root? In Linux, only root can bind to ports below 1024.

Comment: Also when posting to StackOverflow, text should be copied and pasted into the questoin rather than pasting a screenshot.

Comment: yep you are right, I need to run as root thx @Adrian

Comment: when I run it as root, it can't find uvicorn. Any suggestions why?

Comment: I have the same problem. When I run it as sudo, it can't find uvicorn. I can install it with `sudo pip install uvicorn` but then I'm not sure I'm running inside the virtualenv.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way for non-root processes to bind to "privileged" ports on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413807/is-there-a-way-for-non-root-processes-to-bind-to-privileged-ports-on-linux)