# python-telegram-bot webhook doesn't work?

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I take that log when start my bot

```
2020-06-03 17:10:21,867 - telegram.ext.updater - ERROR - unhandled exception in Bot:1023524274:updater
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/maksym/project/univesal_queue_bot/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telegram/ext/updater.py", line 216, in _thread_wrapper
    target(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/maksym/project/univesal_queue_bot/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telegram/ext/updater.py", line 452, in _start_webhook
    self.httpd.serve_forever()
  File "/home/maksym/project/univesal_queue_bot/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telegram/utils/webhookhandler.py", line 52, in serve_forever
    self.http_server.listen(self.port, address=self.listen)
  File "/home/maksym/project/univesal_queue_bot/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 151, in listen
    sockets = bind_sockets(port, address=address)
  File "/home/maksym/project/univesal_queue_bot/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 174, in bind_sockets
    sock.bind(sockaddr)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
2020-06-03 17:10:22,893 - telegram.ext.dispatcher - CRITICAL - stopping due to exception in another thread
```

I use:

python 3.7
python-telegram-bot 12.7
nginx 16+
self-signed certificate

Comment: Sounds like a configuration problem. Did you check the wiki regarding webhooks? https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Webhooks

Comment: Please share more details about your configuration, including the entrypoint Python file.

Answer (score 0):

`python-telegram-bot` by default starts the HTTP webhook server at port 80 ([see source code](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/telegram/ext/updater.py#L446)).

In Linux, only elevated users can run processes that bind to sockets with port numbers below 1024. Either run your app as root (may be a bad idea depending on your setup) with `sudo python yourbot.py`) or allow [Python to bind to privileged ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413807/is-there-a-way-for-non-root-processes-to-bind-to-privileged-ports-on-linux).

Otherwise, there might be another process already using that port.