# WSL2 -Trouble to serve port 80 with node

Tags: node.js, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

### What's I'm trying to do ?

Serve something on port 80 trough nodejs on WSL.

### Commands run

- `npx serve -p 80`
- `sudo npx serve -p 80`

### Error displayed

`Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:80`

***Note: I'm sure port 80 is not busy !***

For example, Docker container run well on port 80:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started
```

### Other example

Here is some command that ✅ work and some that ❌doesn't work

- ✅ docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started
- ❌npx serve
- ❌sudo npx serve
- ✅ npx serve -p 4000
- ❌npm run start (An express server)
- ❌sudo npm run start  (An express server)
- ❌php -S localhost:80
- ✅sudo php -S localhost:80

So it's seems that **node** don't take privilège of **sudo**.
What's i'm missing, is there maybe something wrong on my node installation ?

*EDIT:
I find a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/414258/2838586.
But still doesn't know why it's doesn't work with `sudo` without this fix.*