# Error starting Apach James after installation

Tags: java, spring, james, apache-james

Apache James was not running after starting James Spring a few seconds.`./james start`

Error log on wrapper.log:

```
Caused by: org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /0.0.0.0:465
```

And:

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
```

Is this a firewall problem?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `sudo` as prefix of command helps me. It works like a charm.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind to ports lower than 1024 without running as root.
There are some way to go around this. [Is there a way for non-root processes to bind to "privileged" ports on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413807/is-there-a-way-for-non-root-processes-to-bind-to-privileged-ports-on-linux)
.